# How do you define this statically resolved type parameter?

Tags: f#

given

```
open System
open System.Windows
open System.Windows.Input
open System.ComponentModel

type RelayCommand (canExecute:(obj -> bool), action:(obj -> unit)) =
    let event = new DelegateEvent<EventHandler>()
    interface ICommand with
        [<CLIEvent>]
        member x.CanExecuteChanged = event.Publish
        member x.CanExecute arg = canExecute(arg)
        member x.Execute arg = action(arg)
    member x.CheckCanExecute (sender:obj) (eventArgs:EventArgs) = event.Trigger([| sender;eventArgs  |])
```

how do I write a statically resolved type parameterized function that can satisfy a call to `CheckCanExecute` ?

while this function works it doesn't help me learn statically resolved type parameter syntax

`let checkCanExecute (c:RelayCommand) = c.CheckCanExecute (box this) (EventArgs())`

I expected this to work

`let checkCanExecute (e:^a) = (^a: (member CheckCanExecute: sender:obj -> EventArgs -> unit ) (e, (box me),(EventArgs())))`

but at the callsite 
`checkCanExecute addCommand`

I get *method or object constructor 'CheckCanExecute' not found* (when using the 2nd definition, the 1st compiles just fine)

how do I define a class `let` binding (or member binding if that is a better way to get the job done) that uses [Statically Resolved Type Parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/statically-resolved-type-parameters-%5Bfsharp%5D) to be able to call the method on anything that has the matching method signature?

Comment: Hi Maslow , this may sound funny but I realised I could not figure out what this code is supposed to do :) Not even related to your question (from 7 years ago!) but I'm just curious: what is `CheckCanExecute` supposed to do? You're simply invoking any registered delegates, so why use that name?  Looks like this would allow you to invoke the event with any object and `EventArgs` you want. As I said, just curious what this code may be doing :)

Comment: looks like I was partially trying to translate the idea in WPF of a RelayCommand. I wanted to use SRTPs while doing so. A Relay Command in C# is shown here https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/20c06b/icommand-and-relaycommand-in-wpf/

Answer (score 6):

I think some of the difficulty here is caused by the fact that `CheckCanExecute` is defined as a curried function. For members, it is probably better to go with a tupled function (the way curried functions are compiled is tricky and it might be confusing the statically resolved constraint).

If you change the `RelayCommand` member as follows:

```
 member x.CheckCanExecute (sender:obj, eventArgs:EventArgs) =  
   event.Trigger([| sender;eventArgs  |])
```

And make your `checkCanExecute` an `inline` function that requires tupled function:

```
let inline checkCanExecute (e:^a) = 
  (^a: (member CheckCanExecute: obj * EventArgs -> unit ) (e, box me,(EventArgs())))
```

Then the following type checks:

```
checkCanExecute me
```

Comment: so then, you can't use curried functions with SRTP?

Comment: @Maslow: you can, but you need to write them out in an uncommon way. I added an alternative answer.

Comment: @tomas-petricek should not that (e, box me, ...) be (e, box e, ...) ? sorry for being too lazy to feed this to the compiler and see if I'm missing something :)

Answer (score 6):

If you want to use SRTPs, you cannot curry methods the ordinary way. The member invocation syntax is unable to handle multiple curried arguments at once.

Either you go with .NET-style tupled declarations, as Tomas suggests, or alternatively you must explicitly write out the currying in the form `member x.f a = fun b -> fun c -> ...`.

In your example this would mean:

```
type RelayCommand
    // ...
    member x.CheckCanExecute sender = fun eventArgs -> 
        event.Trigger([| sender;eventArgs  |])        

let inline checkCanExecute (e:^a) = 
    (^a: (member CheckCanExecute: obj -> (EventArgs -> unit)) (e, (box e)) ) <| EventArgs()
```

Comment: Nice one! I was not able to figure out how to make this work :)

Comment: this appears to still require editing the target method(s)? but is a step closer.